# Schedule a job during server start up

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I am using a scheduler for a trigger a event. The scheduled job doesn't run if the server is down during scheduled time. So I need to trigger a event during every server start up. Is there any ways to do so?

Comment: Are you using some sort of library for this? e.g. Quartz Scheduler, or is it just using the java scheduled tasks?

Comment: No I'm not using any such libraries. It is just Java Scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities

1. If you are running your sheduled Job under Windows, you could use Task Sheduler
2. If you are using Linux, you should execute your job in a bash script and put a path to this bash script in `/etc/rc.local` file or add a service. Another possibility is to use Cron Job.

Comment: Yes we can use task scheduler, but my question is what happens to the scheduler if the server is down during the scheduled time.? At that point of time Task scheduler gets failed to process the record.

Comment: Windows Task Sheduler has the possibility to run a Task after server startup or after log on.

Answer (score 0):

We can run a method at spring application context start up(ApplicationListener) time from which we can call the scheduled method directly. So every time when the server gets started, this method runs from which I could able to do what I actually required.
Thanks for the response provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start your job when server starts use `<load-on-startup> any int value </load-on-startup>`on web.xml. it will trigger the servlet. Input value you entered is the priority of the task to start. So in the servlet init method you can call your method.